# Changing the Background of Hyperlinked Item selected in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a list of hyperlinks in an ItemsControl that's bound to a property in the ViewModel. When one is clicked I would like the background of the item to change.

```
<ListBoxItem Source="{Binding ToolsList}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border Name="ItemBorder" BorderThickness="0">
              <TextBlock Margin="2,6">
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=Command}">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                </Hyperlink>
              </TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBoxItem >
```

When I remove the hyperlink lines the selected item is shown.

Thank you!